# ShinyDashboard: Error : argument "value" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build and Shiny app with Shiny Dashboard. But it keeps giving me an error that "argument is missing". I already checked for commas, but it seems okay to me. Can you please help?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

agency=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\agency.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
calendar=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\calendar.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
calendar_dates=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\calendar_dates.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
fare_attributes=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\fare_attributes.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
fare_rules=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\fare_rules.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
feed_info=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\feed_info.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
routes=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\routes.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
stop_times=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\stop_times.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
shapes=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\shapes.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
stops=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\stops.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)
trips=read.table("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ylikool\\statistiline visual\\trips.txt",sep=',',header=TRUE)

calendar_dates$kuup=as.Date(ISOdate(substr(calendar_dates$date,1,4),substr(calendar_dates$date,5,6),substr(calendar_dates$date,7,8)))

number=function(algkoht,loppkoht,kuupaev){
  algus=stops[stops$stop_name==algkoht,c(1,3)]
  lopp=stops[stops$stop_name==loppkoht,c(1,3)]
  alg_trip=stop_times[stop_times$stop_id==algus$stop_id,c(1,4,5)]
  lopp_trip=stop_times[stop_times$stop_id==lopp$stop_id,c(1,4,5)]
  alg_trip=plyr::rename(alg_trip,replace= c("stop_id"="alg_id", "stop_sequence"="alg_jrk"))
  lopp_trip=plyr::rename(lopp_trip, replace=c("stop_id"="lopp_id", "stop_sequence"="lopp_jrk"))
  #common
  koos=merge(alg_trip, lopp_trip, by = intersect(names(alg_trip), names(lopp_trip)))
  #start before finish
  koos1=filter(koos,alg_jrk<lopp_jrk)
  #
  t1=trips[trips$trip_id %in% koos1$trip_id,c(1,2,3,5)]
  #
  p=as.POSIXlt(as.Date(kuupaev))$wday
  paev1=calendar[calendar$service_id %in% t1$service_id,c(1,p+1)]
  paev=paev1[paev1[,p+1]==1,]
  #siit vaatame kas ta erand pole sellel päeval
  erand=calendar_dates[calendar_dates$service_id %in% t1$service_id & calendar_dates$kuup==kuupaev &calendar_dates$exception_type==1,1]
  #paneme kokku ja võtame aint need serviced, mis siis sõidavad
  kuupa=rbind(erand,paev)
  tr=t1[t1$service_id %in% kuupa$service_id,]
  #siit peaks saama bussinumbri
  ka=routes[routes$route_id %in% tr$route_id,c(3,4)]
  return(ka)
}



sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Esileht", tabName = "Esileht"),
    menuItem("Maaliinid", tabName = "Maaliinid")
  )
)

body = dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    # First tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "Esileht",
            fluidRow(
              h1('Rakendus bussiliinide visualiseerimiseks'),
              h3('Tere tulemast!'),
              p('Vastavalt oma soovile vali sobiv tab ja sealt saad vajaliku info'))
),

  # Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "Maaliinid",
          h2('Hinnete osakaalud erinevates valdkondades'),
          box(
            dateInput("Kuup",label="Vali kuupäev"),
            textInput("alg",label='Vali algpeatus'),
            textInput("siht",label='Vali sihtkoht'),
            numericInput('kell',label='Vali kellaaeg')
            ),
          box(
            tableOutput('liinid'))
)
)
)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "App"),
  sidebar,
  body
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$liinid <- renderTable({
  number(input$alg,input$siht,input$Kuup)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server= server
```

THE ERROR:

> ```
> Warning: Error in force: argument "value" is missing, with no default Stack trace (innermost first):
>     65: force
>     64: restoreInput
>     63: numericInput
>     62: tag
>     61: tags$div
>     60: div
>     59: tag
>     58: tags$div
>     57: div
>     56: tag
>     55: tags$div
>     54: div
>     53: box
>     52: tag
>     51: tags$div
>     50: div
>     49: tabItem
>     48: lapply
>     47: tabItems
>     46: tag
>     45: tags$section
>     44: tag
>     43: tags$div
>     42: div
>     41: dashboardBody
>      1: runApp Error : argument "value" is missing, with no default
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify a value for your numericInput. Just write something like:

```
numericInput('kell',label='Vali kellaaeg', value=4)
```